# Minimum number of edges that have to be removed in a graph to make it acyclic

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

Given an undirected graph with n nodes and k edges , find the minimum number of edges that have to be removed in order to attain an acyclic graph. I initially thought that the minimum number of edges that need to be removed is the number of cycles that exist in the graph since each cycle needs one edge to be removed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: But if there is an edge that is contained in more than one cycle, the number of edges we need to remove will be less than the number of cycles. I think answer of this question may change from graph to graph. Did you ask this question from a specific example or is this the original question?

Comment: @ArsenBerk i'm counting the no of cycles by creating the graph edge by edge. Whenever a cycle is detected i don't add that particular edge.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, we combine these observations:

- An acyclic graph is another name for a forest, a union of disjoint trees.
- If a tree has $n \geq 1$ vertices, then it has $n-1$ edges.
- Each connected component has a spanning tree.

If the connected components in the original graph have $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_k$ vertices, then the any union of spanning trees for each component has exactly $$(c_1-1)+(c_2-1)+\cdots+(c_k-1) = (c_1+\cdots+c_k)-k$$ edges.  The number of edges we need to delete is thus $$|E(G)|-(c_1+\cdots+c_k)+k.$$